# Proving $f(f^{-1}(D)) \subset D$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Suppose that $f:A \rightarrow B$ and let $D \subset B$.

For proving $f(f^{-1}(D)) \subset D$:

Let $x \in f(f^{-1}(D))$. Now $f(f^{-1}(D)) \in B$, so $x \in B$. Then $\exists y \in A$ such that $f(y) = x$. This implies $y \in f^{-1}(D)$ and hence $x \in D$. Thus the result follows.

Is this correct?
Is there any other elegant proof?

Comment: Wrong because $B$ is not necessarily the range of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition of $f^{-1}(D)$, $x\in f^{-1}(D)$ if and only if $f(x)\in D$.

This shows $f(f^{-1}(D))=\{f(x)\mid x\in f^{-1}(D)\} \subset D$.